# Django 1.6 getting fk objects

Tags: python, django, join, models, mixing

I have a this models

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    group_owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __str__(self, y):
        return smart_str(self.name)

class Note(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    projectId = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return smart_str(self.title)
```

which i would like to join them in one view, which would be shown when someone enters to this url http://localhost.com:8000/project/ID.
obviously the ID will depend in Project.id and it will have to get all the Notes that are related to it.

Meanwhile my views.py looks like this

```
class ProjectDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'scribere/project/detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Project.objects.filter(group_owner__exact=self.request.user.id)

class ProjectNoteList(generic.ListView):
    context_object_name = 'project_note_list'
    template_name = 'scribere/note/index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Note.objects.filter(userid__exact=self.request.user.id, projectId__exact=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

and the template

```
{% extends "base/adminsNavBar.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block head_title %}{% trans 'Projects Details' %}{% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumbs %}
<div class="breadcrumb"><p>{% trans 'Project Details' %}</p></div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class='row'>
    <a href="{% url 'scribere:project_list' %}" class="btn btn btn-primary pull-right" role="button">{% trans 'Back' %}</a>
    <a href="{% url 'scribere:project_note_list' project.id %}" class="btn btn btn-primary pull-right" role="button">{% trans 'Notes' %}</a>
</div>
<div>
{{project.name}}
</div>
<div class = "note-list">
     <ul>
        {% for note in project_note_list %}
            <li>
                <a href= "#"> {{note}} </a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

which doesn't load any information about the note. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are populating `project_note_list` with some information, there will be nothing to iterate over.

By virtue of the [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)s, and having a [Many to one relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) the `project` object will have a set of notes associated with it, without having to look them up.

You should be able to query them using `project.note_set.all()` or in your template by using:

```
{% for note in project.note_set %}
```

Comment: shouldnt it be `project.note__set` and not `project.note_set`?

Comment: @agconti [Not according to the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

Comment: do i have to declare that project.note__set somewhere?

Comment: @user3399059 No? Of course not? Did you read the documentation I linked you too? Many-to-one relationships are a relatively standard and well handled aspect of the Django framework.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr sorry i read it after my comment, but it's not working...something that i would like to ask is that i'm trying to look at it from Project details , not Note, as in from the parent obj looking for all the kids objs he has not the opposite

Comment: Then you didn't read it well enough. Thats what the Many-to-one relationship article explains. You can quite easily query a ForeignKey relationship from either end.

Comment: for some reason is not working =(, it still shows empty, my bad i forgot i used other context_name for project, it actually worked :D thank you